# prepareforsegue inside CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, swift

I am almost done with my a game. The game consists of a moving boat and we need to avoid moving stones. When boat and the stone collide the game ends. I want to implement a second view controller, which displays the gameover label, game score and a restart button. 
GameOver.swift is another viewcontroller with game score and restart option.

Here is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLBL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectedCoin: UILabel!
    // weak var moveWater: MovingWater!

    var views : [String : UIView]!

    var boat:UIImageView!
    var stone:UIImageView!
    var food:UIImageView!
    var boatWreck:UIImageView!
    var boatLeftRight : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

    var coins = Int()
    var pass = "HELLO"

    var tapTimer:Timer!
    var tapTimer2: Timer!

    var leftM:UInt32 = 55
    var rightM:UInt32 = 250

    var leftS:UInt32 = 35
    var rightS:UInt32 = 220

    func startGame() {
        boat = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boat"))
        boat.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 90)
        boat.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - boat.frame.size.height - 10
        boat.center.x = self.view.bounds.midX

        self.view.addSubview(boat)

        boatLeftRight = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftRight(tap:)))
        boatLeftRight.minimumPressDuration = 0.001
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(boatLeftRight)

        tapTimer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.05), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.change), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func leftRight(tap:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
            if (tapTimer != nil)  {
                self.tapTimer.invalidate()
            }
        } else if tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            let touch = tap.location(in: myView)
            if touch.x > myView.frame.midX {
                tapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.005), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.moveBoat(time:)), userInfo: "right", repeats: true)

            } else {
                tapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.005), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.moveBoat(time:)), userInfo: "left", repeats: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func moveBoat(time:Timer) {

        if let d = time.userInfo as? String! {
            var bot2 = boat.frame

            if d == "right" {
                if bot2.origin.x < CGFloat(rightM) {
                    bot2.origin.x += 2
                }
            } else {
                if bot2.origin.x > CGFloat(leftM) {
                    bot2.origin.x -= 2   
                }
            }
            boat.frame = bot2
        }
    }

    func movingStone() {
        stone = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "stones.png"))
        stone.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 90)
        var stone2 = leftS + arc4random() % rightS

        stone.bounds = CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:81.0, height:124.0)
        stone.contentMode = .center;
        stone.layer.position = CGPoint(x: Int(stone2), y: 10)
        stone.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)

        self.view.insertSubview(stone, aboveSubview: myView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.stone.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height + self.stone.frame.height + 10
        }) { (success:Bool) -> Void in

            self.stone.removeFromSuperview()
            self.movingStone()

        }
    }

    func movingFood() {
        food = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "fishcoin2.png"))

        var stone3 = leftS + arc4random() % rightS

        food.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:81.0, height:124.0)
        food.contentMode = .center;
        food.layer.position = CGPoint(x: Int(stone3), y: 40)
        food.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)

        self.view.insertSubview(food, aboveSubview: myView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.food.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height + self.food.frame.height - 50
        }) { (success:Bool) -> Void in

            self.food.removeFromSuperview()
            self.movingFood()

        }
    }

    func change(tap2: Timer) {
        if(boat.layer.presentation()?.frame.intersects((food.layer.presentation()?.frame)!))!
        {
            coins = coins + 1
            collectedCoin.text = "\(coins)"

            if coins > 100  {

                let a = UIAlertController(title: "WON", message: "WANT AGAIN", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                a.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "A", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

                a.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "B", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (a:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    self.startGame()
                }))
                self.present(a, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        else if(boat.layer.presentation()?.frame.intersects((stone.layer.presentation()?.frame)!))! {

            //this is where boat and stone collide
            //I want to implement the gameoverVC here
            //prepare() is not code sensing in my Xcode
            stopGame()
        }
    }

    func stopGame() {
        tapTimer2.invalidate()

        boat.image = UIImage(named: "wreckboat.png")

        self.stone.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.food.layer.removeAllAnimations()  
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //moveWater.backgroundStart()
        startGame()
        movingStone()
        movingFood()
        coins = 10
        collectedCoin.text = "\(coins)"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController's `prepare(forSegue:)` is not a function that you call. It's called for you, just prior to segueing to a new `ViewController`. In order to show your secondary `ViewController`, you're going to have to create an instance of it and then trigger the segue yourself. Then you'll set up the `prepare()` function to allow your primary viewController to pass data to the secondary one.

Here are the steps you need to make this work:

1. Create an instance of your `GameOver` `ViewController` in Interface Builder.
2. Create a manual segue to it from your first `ViewController` and give it an identifier.
3. Call `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` in your `StopGame()`.
4. If desired, override the primary `ViewController`'s `prepare(for segue:)` to pass data (such as score) to the `GameOver` `ViewController`.

Comment: I am getting the score, in GameOver VC but the problem is I am incrementing the score when boat and coin intersect, I am incrementing it by 1. However, it increments by 28 56 ... What is the reason?

Comment: @PrasannaVigneshwar You're increasing `coins` on *every frame* that boat and coin intersect, so if the boat is touching the coin for 30 frames it will increment 30 times. For ways to solve this, you can ask about it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a new view controller using a segue, you should call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)`.

`prepare` is triggered by calling this function.